# How can I supply 17 showers without a drop in water pressure?

Tags: water-pressure

My question is in relation to hot water reticulation. I want to supply hot water to 17 showers situated on the same floor. How do I go about it in terms of avoiding a drop in pressure when multi showers are in use. Are there any special valves I will need to install along the way?

Comment: This sounds like a commercial installation and might be a bit out of scope for the average 'Home Owner'. This sounds like a project where you might need to consult a commercial plumber that works on things like apartment complexes, gymnasium lockerrooms etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't really DIY-sized.

Answer (score 2):

This is a calculation which depends on supply pressure, flow required, and distance. To avoid unacceptable pressure drop is simply a matter of sizing all piping components properly. It is easy to design a system which minimizes pressure drop and there are numerous on-line calculators you can use: [link to calculator](http://www.tlv.com/global/TI/calculator/water-pipe-sizing-pressure-loss.html).

Your bigger problem will be hot water supply. At 2.5 gpm (a conservative estimate for water-saving type shower head) you will use 42.5 gpm (assuming all showers are in use), a good portion of that will be hot water (ratio unknown as is dependent upon delivery temperature and mix temperature).